# Should the timezone in general settings effect the output of $time = date("g:ia");?

Tags: datetime

I am using the following in a plugin which I would expect to simply output the time of the server.

```
// get current time
$time = date("g:i a");
// outputs 9:36am
```

In a straight `.php` file this is correct - however, from within the plugin the time is an hour out - 8:36am. I imagine this might be to do with British Summer Time. However, in Crafts general settings I have set Timezone to UTC+1 (BST) - Europe/London

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Craft calls `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` when initializing, so PHP will output all times in UTC by default.

If you want to output a time using the timezone that Craft has been set to in General Settings, you can do that with a [DateTime](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/dates/DateTime) object.

```php
$now = new DateTime();
$time = $now->format('g:i a');
```